# How to insert a video (mp4 file) in the masked region using OpenCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, opencv

I am learning OpenCV via some youtube videos and started working on a project which requires me to first mask all the red-coloured regions being caught by my webcam. Next, I want some video file to be played in this masked red colour region. When I try to do that I get this error (this error comes even when I tried inserting an image though):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Deepesh\Environments\cloak\cloak.py", line 30, in <module>
    part1 = cv2.bitwise_and(back, back, mask=mask)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:250: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'cv::binary_op'

[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (436) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

After searching a lot online, I didn't got any satisfactory answers and some answers were too complicated. Can anyone look through this code and correct it so that I can insert a video or even an image for that matter, in the masked red coloured region ?

Here is the code:-

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
back = cv2.imread('./abcd.mp4')

while cap.isOpened():
    # take each frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        # how do we convert rgb to hsv?
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        # cv2.imshow("hsv", hsv)
        # how to get hsv value?
        # lower: hue - 10, 100, 100, higher: h+10, 255, 255
        red = np.uint8([[[0,0,255]]]) # bgr value of red
        hsv_red = cv2.cvtColor(red, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        # get hsv value of red from bgr
        # print(hsv_red)

        # threshold the hsv value to get only red colors`
        l_red = np.array([0, 100, 100])
        u_red = np.array([10, 255, 255])

        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, l_red, u_red)
        # cv2.imshow("mask", mask)

        # all things red
        part1 = cv2.bitwise_and(back, back, mask=mask)
        # cv2.imshow("part1", part1)

        mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

        # part 2 is all things not red
        part2 = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
        # cv2.imshow("mask", part2)

        cv2.imshow("cloak", part1 + part2)

        if cv2.waitKey(5) == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hope to get some replies !

Comment: in `back = cv2.imread()`, you are reading a .mp4 file that is a video file using imread function. Up to my recollection, it should not work or throw some error.

Comment: i tried it with a `.png` file too, it threw the same error even then.

Comment: Or else, after creating the mask image and before bitwise_and operation, convert the mask inage to 3 channel image like this (because back is a 3channel image)- `mask= cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)`